# jquery countdown detect when unit chages

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I working with a countdown plugin from http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html, I have got the countdown functioning to show, months, weeks, days, minutes left until a certain date. What I am wanting to do is try and add in a rollodex effect for when one of the units changes.

However I am struggling to detect when one of the units changes, and I need to do this so I can trigger my animation for the rolodex effect.

Below is my code,

```
    $('.clock').countdown({until:new Date(2012, 11, 31), format: 'odHM', onTick: everyMinute, tickInterval: 60, layout:
    '<div id="timer">' +
        '<div id="timer_labels">'+
            '<div id="timer_months_label" class="timer_labels">Months</div>'+
            '<div id="timer_weeks_label" class="timer_labels">Days</div>'+
            '<div id="timer_days_label" class="timer_labels">Hours</div>'+
            '<div id="timer_minutes_label" class="timer_labels">Minutes</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div id="timer_months" class="timer_numbers"><span>{onn}</span></div>'+
        '<div id="timer_days" class="timer_numbers"><span>{dnn}</span></div>'+
        '<div id="timer_hours" class="timer_numbers"><span>{hnn}</span></div>'+
        '<div id="timer_minutes" class="timer_numbers"><span>{mnn}</span></div>'+
    '</div>'
});
```

Currently my `everyMinute` function that is called in the onTick calledback looks like this,

`function everyMinute() {

         alert("changing")

}`

I have set the tick Interval to 60 which should mean that my everyMinute function is called every 60 seconds however, it seems to be getting called every second, what am I doing wrong?

I have followed the following documentation,

http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#tickInterval

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's a typo in the documentation, but it has the following syntaxt:

```
onTick: updateEvery10Secs: tickInterval: 10});
```

You have:

```
$('.clock').countdown({until:new Date(2012, 11, 31), format: 'odHM', onTick: everyMinute, tickInterval: 60, layout: [...]
```

Which means you should change it to:

```
$('.clock').countdown({until:new Date(2012, 11, 31), format: 'odHM', onTick: everyMinute: tickInterval: 60, layout: [...]
```

Comment: That has to be a typo in their docs, what you've suggested is not valid javascript syntax!

Comment: damn, I was afraid of that. Well, worth a shot.